# Using Yeoman aspnet generators

Tags: asp.net, terminal, yeoman, yeoman-generator, osx-yosemite

I am trying to develop **ASP.NET** applications using a macbook computer with the Yosemite operating system.

I've retrieved the `DNVM` using **Homebrew** with the following commands:

```
brew tap aspnet/dnx
brew update
brew install dnvm
```

I've also setup the ASP.NET generator using the following commands:

```
npm install -g yo generator-aspnet  
npm install -g bower grunt-cli gulp-cli
```

At this point, everything should be ready to go. However, when I type `yo aspnet` in the terminal, it generates an error that states `-bash: yo: command not found`. What could be causing this and is there an easy fix?

I've referenced multiple resources, the two best listed below:
**Reference_01:** https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/aspnet5 
**Reference_02:** http://tattoocoder.azurewebsites.net/vscode-creating-an-application-with-yeoman-aspnet-generators/

**UPDATE**
I made sure to install the following and it still won't recognize `yo aspnet`

- node.js: `brew install node`
- Yeoman: `npm install -g yo`
- Install: `npm install -g generator-aspnet`
- Run: `yo aspnet`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the permissions of your usr/local folders by running the following code:

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local`

`sudo chown -R` **yourUsername** `~/.npm`

`npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower`

Once you have completed this step, reset the **generator-aspnet** by running the following lines of code:

`npm install -g yo generator-aspnet`

`npm install -g bower grunt-cli gulp-cli`

Now you should be able to run your executable line:

`yo aspnet`

Comment: This must be documented... ;)